# Count rows containing specific value based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a better way to do the following task.
I have 2 tables. Table 1 contains the values that I want to look for to count the rows:

```
      A
 1    ID    
 2    a
 3    b
 4    c
 5    d
 6    e
 7    f
```

Table 2 contains data arranged by rows:

```
       A       B     C     D     E     F     G
 1   FileNo Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 Data5 Data6
 2    w1       a     b     a     b     a     b
 3    w1       a     b     a     b     e     f
 4    w2       c     d     c     d     e     f
 5    w1       c     d     c     d     a     b
 6    w1       b     c     b     c     e     f
 7    w2       a     b     a     d     a     b
 8    w3       c     d     c     d     e     f
```

I need to calculate the number of rows that start with "w1" and contain value "a" (and then "b", and "c" and so on, and then same for rows starting with "w2).
The brute-force way, how I see it, would be to use COUNTIF in each row to get 1 or 0 based on existence of the value in the row. Then to use SUMPRODUCT to count the rows based on FileNo criterion and those 1/0. The thing is that above is just an example. I actually have about 40 values in Table 1 and a few thousands in Table 2. Using 40 columns with COUNTIFs in thousands rows looks bulky. I believe there is more elegant way to solve this.

Comment: If your data is in a separate table(separate CSV or workbook) you could query it using query table. See here, but use excel source. http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/microsoft-query.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have to resort to the volatile [OFFSET¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) in order to traverse the rows looking for existence of the ws*x* value coupled with at least one occurance of *a, b, c, d, e* or *f*.

[image: COUNTIF across rows with two criteria]

The *array formula* in J2 is,

```
=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$9999=J$1, SIGN(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($A$2, ROW($1:$9998)-1, 1, 1, 6), $I2))))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Fill J2 right to L2 then fill J2:L2 down to J7:L7.

When transcribing this formula for your own purposes, please note that while `A2:9999` and `ROW(1:9998)` are staggered by a single row, they are the same size and that is important. The `ROW(...)` should always start at *1* but be the same number of rows as the range in column A. You are looking for the *position within* A2:A9999, not the physical row number on the worksheet.

I've attempted to colour match the results from ws1 in order that you can easily identify working results from that criteria pair.

¹<sub>[OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) is considered a volatile function that recalculates whenever anything in the workbook changes.</sub>

Comment: @Abyrvalg - btw, my apologies. I answered an almost identical question earlier today that relied on single criteria and originally marked yours as a potential duplicate. The addition of a second criteria made this question more than sufficiently different to warrant its own posting.